# Cast uint to int

Tags: type-casting

My function receives a bytes string. I convert one byte to an uint8.

`uint8 u_number = uint8(data[0]);`

I now want to pass this number to a function that only accepts `int64`, so I need to cast it first.

`int64 i_number = int64(u_number);`

This gives an error `TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint8" to "int64".`. Note, that an implicit conversion also does not work `int64 i_number = u_number;`.

What works (and I think it shouldn't) is converting a uint8 to an int8 - this is surprising because in this case overflows can occur.

So how do I convert an uint8 to an int64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:
`int64 i_number = int64(uint64(u_number))`